# How do i implement iOS style delete in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, flutter-cupertino

I am looking to implement iOS type delete in flutter.
Please see image below. Is there a widget which provides this functionality? Or do i need to implement it myself?
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsByj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the widget [Dismissible](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) can help you. But if you search a ready solution, here a package called [flutter_slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)

Comment: I am looking for something which has the red minus button delete implementation. I do not think these widget have that.

Comment: can u specify which part of the behaviour u feel missing from the Dismissible widget?

Comment: If it’s only the icon, u can set it to show that icon instead

Comment: Basically, what i want is when I tap on a button, i want the red minus button to appear on the left of the tile. and then i can tap on it to remove the particular tile.